# Rails3 Foreign Primary Keys Wrong Way Round

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a straight forward has_many through relationship in my RoR3.2.1 application. The only change is that I'm using a different foreign / primary key as I'm working with a legacy database.

For some reason, when I create a new record, the values save in the wrong fields. Groupname saves into username and vice versa.

My radusers have many radgroups through radusergroups. My join table has columns username and groupname.

Raduser.rb:

```
has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => :groupname, :primary_key => :username
has_many :radgroup, :through => :radusergroup
```

Radgroup.rb:

```
has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :raduser, :through => :radusergroup
```

Radusergroup.rb

```
belongs_to :raduser, :primary_key => :username
belongs_to :radgroup, :primary_key => :groupname, :foreign_key => :username
```

I have this in my form:

```
- Radgroup.all.each do |radgroup|
  = check_box_tag "raduser[radgroup_ids][]", radgroup.id, @raduser.radgroup.include?(radgroup), :id => "raduser_radgroup_id_#{radgroup.id}"
  = radgroup.groupname
```

When I hit save, my records save the wrong way around:

```
INSERT INTO `radusergroup` (`groupname`, `id`, `priority`, `username`) VALUES ('username1233', NULL, 1, 'groupname123')
```

And the table:

```
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+
| username         | groupname    | priority | id |
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+
| groupname123     | username1233 |        1 |  1 |
+------------------+--------------+----------+----+
```

Anyone out there able to help with this?

---- EDIT ADDED TRACE AS PER ANSWER BELOW ----

```
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `visible_action?'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:18:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:61:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:115:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.0) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2911347278127141110__call__2925805972906996448__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

--- SESSION DUMP ---

```
_csrf_token: "YepneklJ9OWdmKHVVclxGzrg5ECbk11a9B3tJJtoECU="
session_id: "8cec81c93085d17dc744f1a44a7054b6"
warden.user.user.key: ["User", [1], "$2a$10$J.oF0HRrE0PokqkQ2S4gwO"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no :primary_key option for associations. That has to be defined within the class. Can you try changing your classes to this:

Raduser.rb:

```
primary_key :username

has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => :username
has_many :radgroup, :through => :radusergroup
```

Radgroup.rb:

```
primary_key :groupname

has_many :radusergroup, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => :radgroup
has_many :raduser, :through => :radusergroup
```

Radusergroup.rb

```
belongs_to :raduser, :foreign_key => :username
belongs_to :radgroup, :foreign_key => :groupname
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense - having tried this though I get an errro: undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Can you print the stack trace?